# Strange result when combining assignment and equality in if statement (PHP)

Tags: php, debugging

Tested in PHP 5.3.10 on CentOS.

In a script a run:

```
$test = "62 3/4";

if($pos = strpos($test,' ') !== false) {
  $test= substr($test,0,$pos); // use $pos
}
// $test is "6"
```

And in another independent script I run:

```
if($pos = strpos($test,' ') !== false) {
  $test = substr($test,0,strpos($test,' ')); // redo substr calculation
}
// $test is "62"
```

$pos should be 2 (the third character is a space, starting from zero, 0,1,2), so both $test should be "62", no?

Comment: better to use $test = "62 3/4"; instaed $test = "62.75"..???

Comment: Certainly better to use 62.75, but I'm just trying to handle some bad data that got imported through excel. 62 is better than 6, though not quite as good as 63 or 62.75. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operator precedence! `!==` comes before `=`, so the test effectively becomes

```
if($pos = (strpos($test,' ') !== false))
```

which is going to evaluate to either true or false, not the string position.

Always use explicit parens:

```
if(($pos = strpos($test,' ') !== false)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
if( ($pos = substr($test, ' ')) !== false ) {
    // ...
}
```

See [PHP Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Answer (score 0):

Also consider that in your second if, the value of the variable $test was already changed by the first: $test= substr($test,0,$pos);

Comment: Ok but those aren't actually running together. I ran one, then the other.